# Optimize SQL function in C# code

Tags: c#, sql

I'm running into an issue with an application that's leading me to a method doing the following.

```
protected override int GetCount(List<int> itemlist)
{
    sql.Execute(@"TRUNCATE Table table0");
    int count = 0;

    foreach (int itemgroup in itemlist)
    {
        count += sql.Execute(@"  INSERT  INTO table0 (ID, Guid)
                                    SELECT  table1.ID , table1.Guid
                                    FROM    dbo.tablefunction(@p0) table1 LEFT JOIN
                                            dbo.table0 ON table1.ID = table0.ID
                                    WHERE   table0.ID IS NULL", itemgroup);
    }
    return count;
}
```

i'm running into a key constraint issue during the insert loop which isn't completely unexpected.

But I'm also noticing that it's potentially doing multiple varied size inserts so I'm looking for ideas/suggestions on dynamically assembling a union query and then inserting all results at once. For example,the resulting query might be

```
WITH b AS
(
    SELECT  table1.ID , table1.Guid
    FROM    dbo.tablefunction(item0) table1 LEFT JOIN
            dbo.table0 ON table1.ID = table0.ID
    WHERE   table0.ID IS NULL

    UNION

    SELECT  table1.ID , table1.Guid
    FROM    dbo.tablefunction(item1) table1 LEFT JOIN
            dbo.table0 ON table1.ID = table0.ID
    WHERE   table0.ID IS NULL
)
INSERT  INTO table0 (ID, Guid)
SELECT * FROM b
```

I'm just not sure how best to go about it.

Comment: It's not really related to your dynamically sized insert, but can this code be called from more than one place simultaneously? If so what happens if the table gets TRUNCATEd by another instance after you inserted the values, so you no longer have the values you should have but an empty table instead?

Comment: there's a lock preventing this from being run simultaneously. but the table it's inserting too is used by the next set of methods in the sequence and then rinse and repeat, hence the truncation. There's probably better ways to do the whole thing, but I'm hoping to keep this change isolated to this method to avoid larger regressions

Comment: So what is the problem exactly with composing that union statement? Seems like a bunch of string concatenations.

Comment: Can you show source of dbo.tablefunction()? Maybe it is possible to update it's logic and pass all values from your itemList? So query would be much simpler without unions...

Comment: Modifying the tablefunction would be my preferred method, but without a lot more review to determine where else it's used I'm worried about causing other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use string.format() method :

```
protected override int GetCount(List<int> itemlist)
        {
            sql.Execute(@"TRUNCATE Table table0");
            int count = 0;

            foreach (int itemgroup in itemlist)
            {
                string sql = string.Format(@"  INSERT  INTO table0 (ID, Guid)
                                    SELECT  table1.ID , table1.Guid
                                    FROM    dbo.tablefunction({0}) table1 LEFT JOIN
                                            dbo.table0 ON table1.ID = table0.ID
                                    WHERE   table0.ID IS NULL", itemgroup);

                count += sql.Execute(sql);
            }
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: the sql.Execute method is already doing that elsewhere in code. The issue I'm trying to tackle is that this foreach loop is rerunning the same small query and doing a larger number of varied inserts which I'd like to combine into a single more efficient insert

Comment: String sql = empty string and then concatenate to it in each iteration of the loop (as you've basically done?) But the sql.execute would have to be outside the loop, with the generated string - once you've concatenated all the required statements - just being executed once, so only one round trip.

Comment: Why are you doing it more than once?  In the code posted and elsewhere?

Comment: it's a small part of a really big, probably dirty nested set of functions handling grouping at a number or tiers....there's a reason I'm trying not to edit anything outside this method.

Comment: Then do it twice.  Leave old code alone and do it correct in your new code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Table-Valued Parameters - msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx) and a stored procedure to do this.

First, you would need to create a table type to use with the procedure:

```
create type dbo.ItemGroups_udt as table (ItemGroup int not null);
go
```

Then, create the procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.table0_truncate_and_insert (
  @ItemGroups as dbo.ItemGroups_udt readonly
) as 
begin;
  set nocount, xact_abort on;

  truncate table table0;

  insert into table0 (id, guid)
  select tvf.id, tvf.guid
  from @ItemGroups as i
    cross apply dbo.tablefunction(i.ItemGroup) as tvf;

end;
go
```

If you run in to constraint violoations then distinct, group by, or other conditions may be necessary

Then, assemble and pass the list of item groups to the stored procedure using a `DataTable` added as a `SqlParameter` using `SqlDbType.Structured`.

Table Valued Parameter Reference:

- [SQL Server 2008 Table-Valued Parameters and C# Custom Iterators: A Match Made In Heaven! - Leonard Lobel](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/)
- [Table Value Parameter Use With C# - Jignesh Trivedi](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/table-value-parameter-use-with-C-Sharp/)
- [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)
- [Maximizing Performance with Table-Valued Parameters - Dan Guzman](http://www.dbdelta.com/maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters/)
- [Maximizing throughput with tvp - sqlcat](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2013/09/23/maximizing-throughput-with-tvp/)
- [How to use TVPs with Entity Framework 4.1 and CodeFirst](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179481/Code-First-Stored-Procedures)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up coming up with. I may have been pre-coffee earlier when I was looking at this. It could probably still use a little work but it should work.

```
protected override int GetCount(List<int> itemlist)
{
    sql.Execute(@"TRUNCATE Table table0");
    int count = 0;

    string sql = @"WITH b AS
                    (
                        {0}
                    )
                    INSERT  INTO table0 (ID, Guid)
                    SELECT ID, Guid
                    FROM b";

    List<string> sqlsubs = new List<string>();

    foreach (int itemgroup in itemlist)
    {
        sqlsub.Add( string.Format(@"SELECT  table1.ID , table1.Guid
                                    FROM    dbo.tablefunction({0}) table1 LEFT JOIN
                                            dbo.table0 ON table1.ID = table0.ID
                                    WHERE   table0.ID IS NULL", itemgroup));
    }

    string sqlunion = string.Join(" UNION ", sqlsub);

    return context.Execute(string.Format(sql, sqlunion));
}
```